# Continuing page number in LaTeX

Tags: page-numbering

I want to continue the roman numbering of the front matter of my document after the main matter is finished. The following, unfortunately, does not work. The counter start over with 1.

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
...

\setcounter{savepage}{\number\value{page}}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum{}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{\number\value{savepage}}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{appendix}
\section*{Appendix}

\end{appendix}
```

Comment: BTW, `\setcounter{page}{\number\value{savepage}}` can be shortened to `\setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}`. `\value` addresses the count register of the specified counter and it can directly be used in `\setcounter`.

Comment: BTW: `appendix` is no environment, so `\appendix`, not `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}`. If you use the `appendix` package, then it's `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}`.

Answer (score 7):

`\pagenumbering` does the following two things (from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne
  \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}
```

- The page number is set to one (`\global\c@page \@ne`)
- The page number representation is changed to use the argument (`\gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}`)

Since it's resetting the page number to one, your saving and restoring of the page number doesn't stick. So, instead, use the following order of coding:

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}
```

Note that this will make the first page within the appendix be equivalent to the last page in your *front matter*. If you want it to start one page further, use

```
\setcounter{page}{\numexpr\value{savepage}+1}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `\stepcounter{savepage}` after the `\setcounter` in the front matter.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more complicate than Werner's solution, but with the possibility of storing whole 'counter' trees.

Use the package `xassoccnt`, define a `backup counter group`, say `pagebackup`, populate it with the `page` counter, store the state into some id (say, `roman`) and restore it later on, after changing the counter output to `roman` again with `\pagenumbering`.

In the example of usage below, the first five pages are numbered with roman figures and the appendix numbering continues with `vi`, as requested.

I agree, that this is 'too' much for such one occasion, but good to know for other issues.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\DeclareBackupCountersGroupName{pagebackup}
\AssignBackupCounters[name=pagebackup]{page}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}



\pagenumbering{roman}

\blindtext[20]

\clearpage
\BackupCounterGroup[backup-id=roman]{pagebackup}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]


\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\RestoreBackupCounterGroup[backup-id=roman]{pagebackup}

\appendix
\section*{Appendix}
\blindtext[50]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks to all of you!
@Werner, switching lines worked perfectly!

Comment: @Tobi1990: I think your line should be under Werner's post, not mine ;-)