# Pause page numbering on inserting pdf, then resume after pdf

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages, xassoccnt

My thesis has pdfs inserted like this, and using `xassoccnt` to store the page number before the pdf is inserted, then start from this page number after. I've used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353916/268876) as a starting point.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.8in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{pdfpages} %using demo mode as Overleaf takes too long to compile.

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\begin{document}
\DeclareBackupCountersGroupName{pagebackup}
\AssignBackupCounters[name=pagebackup]{page}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}

\section{Publication I}

\clearpage
\BackupCounterGroup[backup-id=pub1]{pagebackup} %store page number (page 2)
\newpage

\setlength{\originalVOffset}{\voffset}   
\setlength{\originalHOffset}{\hoffset}

\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\includepdf[pages=-]{1-introduction/publication_01.pdf}
\setlength{\voffset}{\originalVOffset}
\setlength{\hoffset}{\originalHOffset}

\clearpage
\RestoreBackupCounterGroup[backup-id=pub1]{pagebackup} %should start at 3, but gives an error

\section{}
\end{document}
```

This gives me an error on the `\RestoreBackupCounterGroup` line; `Missing number, treated as zero.` And predictably, the page number *after* the pdf is now zero. What am I missing?

The page numbering should go, for example;

1

2

pdfpage (no number)

pdfpage (no number)

pdfpage (no number)

pdfpage (no number)

3

4

Answer (score 1):

Don't need any package to achieve that. Just record the original page number and set the page number after the PDFs have been included.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.8in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe} % For generate the example-image.pdf
\usepackage{pdfpages} %using demo mode as Overleaf takes too long to compile.

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% record original page number %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{opagenum}
\setcounter{opagenum}{\thepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}
\section{Publication I}


\clearpage
\newpage

\newlength{\originalVOffset}
\newlength{\originalHOffset}
\setlength{\originalVOffset}{\voffset}   
\setlength{\originalHOffset}{\hoffset}

\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}

\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{example-image.pdf}

\setlength{\voffset}{\originalVOffset}
\setlength{\hoffset}{\originalHOffset}
\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% make the original page number plus one %
% and set it as current page number      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\stepcounter{opagenum}
\makeatletter
\global\c@page \theopagenum
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Test1}

\clearpage
\section{Test2}
\end{document}
```

There is another way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.8in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe} %For generate the example-image.pdf
\usepackage{pdfpages} %using demo mode as Overleaf takes too long to compile.

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% record original page number %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{opagenum}
\setcounter{opagenum}{\thepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}
\section{Publication I}


\clearpage
\newpage

\newlength{\originalVOffset}
\newlength{\originalHOffset}
\setlength{\originalVOffset}{\voffset}   
\setlength{\originalHOffset}{\hoffset}

\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}

\includepdf[
pagecommand={
\setcounter{page}{\theopagenum}% add command to set page number won't go up
\thispagestyle{empty}% The default code in pagecommand
},
pages=-
]{example-image.pdf}

\setlength{\voffset}{\originalVOffset}
\setlength{\hoffset}{\originalHOffset}
\clearpage
\section{Test1} %should start from opagenum + 1

\clearpage
\section{Test2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was able to make the second solution work (see my edit). The first I can't get to add one to the original page number. Thanks!

Comment: Actually , I have a little bit confused about your question. How many pages you external PDF will be? If it is only one page. You don’t need to do anything, the after page always start from 3. If it is multiple pages, it not make sense to make the after page start from 3.

Comment: For both my answers, the after page are start from 2 not 3. That is what I think it should be achieved. As you said in title, make page numbering pause and resume after.

Comment: Is 3 the really result you wanna achieve? So in first answer, you just put one more`\stepcounter{opagenum}` before `\makeatletter`. Then the after page will start from 3.

Comment: the external pdf (a publication) will be multiple pages, not just one. My university requires in a thesis that the page numbering is paused for the *whole* pdf and then resumed thereafter. i.e. 2 , several pdf pages , 3

Comment: Hi @blanky, more confused. As you said, that is what my original method to achieve. After your edit, now the page number look like 2 , several pdf pages , 4. That's wrong, right?

Comment: Yes, my bad @Tom. I was putting ```\setcounter{opagenum}{\thepage}``` in the wrong place. Your solution works perfectly.